How do I de-obfuscate this PowerShell command
Long time reader, first time poster.
I recently read an article on command line obfuscation and I need an adult to explain to me Barney style how does

( [sTrING]::JOIn(”
,(’39s33-43%114y56F116j114%57V116y43V41-36k111F46V96V110k46y37-46m96j121s106s102V103-111m46s32k41F33V43s114s57s116%114y56F116%43y36k111k46k38-104s46F37F46m101s101%46-32′.SPlIt(
‘y-sm%kjV>F’ ) | FOreach-OBject{ [ChAR] ( $_ -BXOr 0x09 )} )) )

possibly turn into

(ipconfig /all)

I thought I understood PowerShell before this... and the mentioned functions all make sense individually, but I basically do not understand what happens here.

So, I managed to deobfuscate your post so I could explain the obfuscation of the command.
It's actually pretty simple.
First, you have the string 39s33-43%114y56F116j114%57V116y43V41-36k111F46V96V110k46y37-46m96j121s106s102V103-111m46s32k41F33V43s114s57s116%114y56F116%43y36k111k46k38-104s46F37F46m101s101%46-32
The string is then separated in a array of string with the method .Split() using the string y-sm%kjV>F as value.
This results, basically, in REMOVING every character present in y-sm%kjV>F from the string.
NOTE WELL: this only works in Powershell 5.1, Powershell 7.x requires casting to [char] array: .split([char[]]'y-sm%kjV>F')
The result is equal to 393343114561161145711643413611146961104637469612110610210311146324133431145711611456116433611146381044637461011014632
I rendered it here as a single [string]: it's actually a [string] array, every character an item.
And this [string] array is piped to Foreach-Object which performs the operations in its scriptblock on every item of the array(read: on every character), represented in the scriptblock as $_.
The operation is a Bitwise XOr shift which, basically, changes the value of the character by 0x09(which is written as a hexodecimal value for greater obfuscation) and then returning the result as a [char] value, resulting into a [char] Array.
All of this happens incapsulated in the ::Join() static method of the [string] class, which merges the resulting [char] array into a single [string], each element separated by the first parameter in the method which in this case is empty(so no separation).
the resulting [string] is .("{1}{0}" -f'ig','ipconf') ("{0}{1}"-f'/a','ll') which is composed by two [string] formatting(resulting into ipconfig and  /all) and a dot-source to launch them as command.
in short: split a string into a array to remove usless pieces, convert the elements of the array, join back the array in a string, process the string as a command.

I now realize that I somehow managed to mess up the order of operations.
Thank you so much!  You have definitely saved what remains of my hair.

I mean, the whole point of obfuscation is making harder to understand what's going on so don't hit yourself too hard.
